# desserializar xml c#

Tags: c#, xml, desserialização

Fiz uma chamada através do meu web api e coloquei em uma classe. Como eu exibo os valores?

xml:

```
<result>
<resourceName>activity</resourceName>
<size>1</size>
<entries>
<entry id="1802274" link="/activity/1802274.xml"/>
</entries>
</result>
```

pego o xml:

```
public class PegaVisita
    {

        HttpClient client;
        Uri usuarioUri;

        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task GeraLocalAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.umov.me");
                    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("CenterWeb/api/meutoken/activity.xml?description=Cancelar&Coletas").Result;

                    string tarefa = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tarefa);
                        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
                        {
                            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Result));
                            var Teste = (Result)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                        }


                        usuarioUri = response.Headers.Location;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.Write("Erro ao cadastrar os locais");
                Console.Write("Error : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

classe que recebe o xml

```
namespace WsCliMotoristas
{
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("result"), XmlType("rstult")]
    public class Result
    {
        [XmlElement("resourceName")]
        public string resourceName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("size")]
        public string size { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Não caio em nenhuma exception, está fazendo tudo corrreto. Só preciso saber como resgatar os valores das classes, exibi-los ou gravá-los no banco, por exemplo

Comment: O _XmlType_ da classe está correto? Está "rstult", não deveria ser "result"?

Comment: Inclua essas informações, editando a sua pergunta original e apague essa.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [desserializar xml](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/317927/desserializar-xml)

Comment: Além do misstype você também não está serializando o elmento `<entries>`e seu tipo `<entry>`

Comment: Arrumei o erro do result, o entries eu não queria serializar mesmo

Comment: [XmlElement("entries")]
        public object entries { get; set; } Adicionei ele agora

Comment: Nãor recebo nenhum erro. Eu queria conseguir visualzar o conteudo desserializado

Comment: Experimentou colocar um breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente desta forma:

```
namespace WsCliMotoristas
{
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("result"), XmlType("result")]
    public class Result
    {
        [XmlElement("resourceName")]
        public string resourceName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("size")]
        public string size { get; set; }
        [XmlArray("entries")]
        public List<entry> entries { get; set; }

        [XmlType("entry")]
        public class entry
        {
            [XmlAttribute("id")]
            public string id { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute("link")]
            public string link { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Já com o `XmlType` do "result" resolvido e as entradas `entries` e `entry` adicionadas.

Se eventualmente não quiser obter informação do `entries` coloque o `XmlIgnore`.

Comment: Fiz essas alterações, está tudo certinho... Como eu vejo as informações desserializadas?

Comment: Supostamente a variável _Teste_ tem o objeto com a informação.

Comment: Consegui!! muito obrigado. Agora estou tentando pegar o alternativeidentifier, Como eu acesso o item da lista criada? [XmlType("schedule")]
        public class schedule
        {
            [XmlElement("alternativeIdentifier")]
            public string alternativeIdentifier { get; set; }
  
        }

Comment: Se calhar será melhor editar a sua questão e colocar lá essa nova estrutura, porque esse _schedule_ não está na definição inicial do XML.